# How do you search a 2-D list for a single word?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, if

```
list = [['hngbhsjehtt'], ['bhnsghappyj'], ['jknmsgnhdbg']]
word = 'happy'
```

how do i search the list for happy?
the output should be index 2, index 5

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is a 2-D list, but each cell contains a string and according to your question you are trying to find out the substring index too. Therefore the result should contain three numbers.

```python
list = [['hngbhsjehtt'], ['bhnsghappyj'], ['jknmsgnhdbg']]

def search_matrix(matrix, word):
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, text in enumerate(row):
           z = text.find(word)
           if z == -1:
               continue
           return i, j, z
    return -1, -1, -1

search_matrix(list, 'happy')

# 1, 0, 5
```